# Pulling out specific characters that are combined in a single column

Tags: excel

I have a data extract that resulted in fields being combined into column A like this:

```
Sales Figures Report pg 121
Walmart Inc. 001230134 99 Associates Parkway 56.12 20.00 10.00 86.12 00 1
1400.25 262.40 14.50 1677.15 02 9
50.00 100.25 10.00 160.25 00 1
1400.25 262.40 14.50 1677.15 02 9
```

There are over 50,000 rows in this sort of format, some are a little different as they'll start with vendor information and then have those values after (still all in col. A). In the above example 1677.15 is the combined value of the three numbers before that, i.e. the total amount due.

Originally I wanted to basically separate out each value using things like `left()`, `mid()`, `right()` etc. however at this point all I want is the total figure, i.e. the $1677.15 in the above example. What is the best non-vba method of doing this?

Two issues:

- The problem is that the amounts are not always the same number of digits (can range from $xx.xx to $xxx,xxx.xx)
- Since There are multiple "." you can't use search() to find the correct character location.

Comment: The first question is, where is this terribly exported data coming from that can't produce the data is a logical format like CSV, JSON, SQL file, etc?)   If you absolutely have to use data formatted like then, then what is the pattern?  Can you give some more sample data?  For example, based on your sample I'm guessing the number you need is always _"the number starting after the *3rd* blank space_, on_ every **3rd** and **5th** row_  (and 8th, 10th, 13th, etc)??

Comment: How you will detect which value it will search for as there is no specific clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the **Total** figure is always the third group from the end.  That being the case, you can use the following formula and defined names:

```
=IFERROR(--INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1),"")
```

**Defined Names**

```
seq refers to:      =ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
seq_99 refers to:   =IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99)
```

In the formula,

- `SUBSTITUTE`: Replace all spaces with a large number (99) of spaces
- `MID` Return an array consisting of each word (space separated)
- `TRIM` the words to remove the extra spaces
- `INDEX` Return the item that is third from the end.
- `IFERROR` handle lines such as your first, which does not contain the relevant pattern.
- *`seq` and `seq_99` return arrays of `{`1,2,3,...}`and`{1,99,198,...}` to be used in the formulas*

[image]

Comment: trying to get this to work right now, at least from your screen it's clear it works. Will check you off once I get it working. Are seq and seq_99 custom formulas you made from vba functions?

Comment: No VBA.  They are **Defined Names**.  Depending on your version of Excel, you may find the Defined Names tab on the formula ribbon.  Learn more by typing **Defined Names** into your help bar in Excel.  The formulas used for these names are in my Answer.  If you have Excel 2016, you can also use the `FILTERXML` function to split, but the method I provided will work in most any version.